# Why isn't it the norm to put a "TL;DR" one-line answer at the top of an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, best-practices

It's worth to mention that I'm still a newbie on Physics SE and SE in general, but during this year or so I found that different sites have different "standard" ways of answering (and there's nothing wrong with that in principle). As an example, the Role-playing Games' answers almost all have the same structure:

**Big, concise answer**

Paragraph(s) explaining the answer

Eventual paragraph(s) on related topics or specifications

like [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/172617/53140), and personally, I find it *very* easy to understand and I try to always answer in a similar manner, as opposed to "specifications, then answer but not clearly stated", like [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/568885/220004). Is there a reason why a lot of people don't do this? Is it just different ways of explaining for different people, or is it a site-related thing?

Disclaimer: I'm not talking about those awesome huge answers that explain everything in a great detail better than a physics book, nor about opinion-based answers (but they shouldn't belong to the site anyway). I'm talking about "normal" answers.

Comment: I think it is because the answers of the RPG SE have more likely a single-sentence summary. Most PSE answers have not. My another reason to not answer on this way is that it would look as if I would want to attract attention on an unfair way. However, I still like to answer with a summary in the first sentence, and then explaining it in the body.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. You're just asking why all users don't put a bold, one sentence answer at the top of their answers?

Comment: If you don’t like an answer there’s the possibility to vote it down or add a comment requesting additional information.

Comment: It just looks gaudy to me. It looks like the flavorless, nuance-free, SEO-optimized and click-optimized "content" that pollutes lesser sites.

Comment: The marking "TL;DR" is originally an editing mark meaning "Too long; Didn't read". That's not a compliment to your writing, it's a statement that you filled the text with too much junk.  The editor is telling you to cut what's below not complimenting you on having written a good summary.  So an answer that marks itself or part of itself "TL;DR" is basically saying you did a poor job of writing your own answer.  Now if you wanted to ask why people don't write a summary of their answer at the top before getting into detail, that's a different question....

Answer (score 11):

It's really just personal preference in how one chooses to construct the answer.

Sometimes people will put a "TL;DR" at the top, or the bottom, to summarize things which is kind of what you're looking for. Not everybody does though.

The "issue" you describe, where you get a lot of extra information and details before the punchline, is a trend that I notice in my work with other scientists and engineers. I can't tell you how many times a yes or no question gets a 10 minute response in a meeting where somebody tells us about all possible options and not just the one we asked about.

Part of this could be related to academic writing training -- a formal journal paper isn't really constructed in the way you describe. They tend to be structured with a background, a methods/equations/etc section, results, discussion, and the conclusions. The style of writing you refer to is more like what journalists do -- it's called an [inverted pyramid style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_pyramid_(journalism)) of writing.

The inverted pyramid is pretty useful because it let's people read as deeply as they need to in order to understand the point. When possible, I try to write my answers along similar lines -- and I also try to structure my journal articles similarly, at least for the abstract and then within each section, but that's a work in progress (like writing always is)!

Comment: This clarifies it, thanks.

Comment: "a formal journal paper isn't really constructed in the way you describe" -- indeed. It would be a real drag to have to write a quick, complete, 250-word TL;DR jab at the top of every paper that explained in a concise way what the whole thing was about. Oh, wait...